# MessageBox.Show() does not work outside debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new to C# and Visual Studio. I wrote a simple forms app that works great in debug. When I build and run the exe everything works except MessageBox.Show() does not pop up any message. So I built a new project with one form, one button, and one event handler.

Sure enough. The message box pops up when using Start With Debugging.

Nothing happens when I click the button with using Start Without Debugging.

Some research pointed me at:

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public enum UIPermissionWindow { AllWindows }
```

I added that and still not pop-up from any message boxes.
The project is as basic as possible for troubleshooting.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public enum UIPermissionWindow { AllWindows }

namespace Form462
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => MessageBox.Show("Help!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which environment are you using? Visual Studio 2017? If you manually execute the .exe file in the Debug folder, does it work?

Comment: When I run the exe from the Debug folder.  The form loads but when you click on the button no message box appears.  Running it with debugging in VS clicking the button pops open the window as expected.

Comment: I do see, 1 message.
Message IDE1006 Naming rule violation: These words must begin with upper case characters: button1_Click

Comment: Change that to `=> Close();` and check if the form closes. If it does, then the issue is with the Message Box. If it doesn't, it's not even calling your method. But I can't think of a reason for that popup not to display. Do you have a multi monitor setup?

Comment: Close() is working totally normal.  That is strange, I wonder what's up with MessageBox.Show()

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Comment: Can you try making it into a "regular method" instead of the `=>` shortcut?

Comment: Also clean and rebuild your solution, who knows you might get lucky in the big city

Comment: It's a single monitor.  I am remoted into it.

Comment: private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nope");
        }

Comment: This also bombs out

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Cleaned and started without debugging.  Still acting like a dead fish rather than a button.

Comment: OK, so this is messed up.  I copied it off the remote server and onto my desktop and the popup is there.

Comment: im wondering if its popping off screen

Comment: That is so bizarre.  I need to change the title to MessageBox.Show() Does not work on Remote Desktops I guess.

Comment: That's a good point Michael.  It could be popping off the screen.  Maybe I can force it to display center screen?

Comment: Can you try `MessageBox.Show(this, "Help!")`

Comment: MessageBox should always be center screen, it looks like its actually hard to make it pop up else where.  It's got to be something with the RDP.

Comment: Did you try `this` ?

Comment: Tried with the this reference same issue, but only in the RDP session.

Comment: Also tried cascade windows, show windows stacked, I shook my fist at it : )

Comment: This might have been covered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849651/messagebox-show-appear-over-remote-desktop-connection

Comment: Does it work, however thats the point of `this`

Comment: private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Nope","Not at all",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,(MessageBoxOptions)0x40000);
        }

Comment: Still nothing on the remote desktop window.

Comment: Im wondering if user32 will work `[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`
    `public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);` `MessageBox(new IntPtr(0), "Hello World!", "Hello Dialog", 0);`

Comment: I just tried a winforms app in remote desktop and it worked just fine. What OS are you using in each workstation? Does the form with the button respond to clicks or dragging after pressing the button?

Comment: @Andrew yeah there is no normal reason why this wouldnt be working, also he has tried cascade windows and its still not visible. its a good question to ask if the form can be moved though, and would be indicative of a shown ownered window that isnt visible

Comment: Michael, thanks again this is a cool suggestion.  Still doesn't work when running outside of Debugg.  I have to wonder if it is this VM I'm using.  If it fails on another VM, I'm giving up and using some other method to tell the user the button was clicked.

Comment: This will be run on Server 2012.   Looks like I can drag the form around but still no popup from button click event.

Comment: Which means its not creating the dialog at all, try another dialog, like `var frm = new Form();` `frm.ShowModal();`

Comment: Like this is basic windows stuff, if it cant create a dialog on vm, windows wouldnt work, so something is definitely suspect

Comment: Interesting... Form does not contain a definition for ShowModal()

Comment: Form.ShowDialog

Answer (score 1):

**Windows corruption is clearly the culprit.**  MessageBox.Show() works perfectly normal on another server.
One other odd thing on this server, Can't seem to open dialog boxes in Visual Studio.
File --> Open ---> New Project Solution.

Nothing happens.  I see the little Ready Icon in the way bottom left blink, nothing else happens.  I have no updates for Visual Studio or windows.

Comment: Oh. Can you try reinstalling Visual Studio? Just in case, also run `chkdsk` on your drives. You can also try running `sfc /scannow` in a CMD window with administrator privileges to look for possible damaged system files.

Comment: I did even better.  Nuked the VM.  Made a new VM.  I find that kind of Windows corruption is no fun to play around with.

Comment: And the project is almost done.  Thanks again to everyone who gave there time to answer questions.  S.O. rules.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was due to another process blocking all pop-ups on the machine.